# AJAX not working, updating database via JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've made game in phaser (JS library for games) and i now want to make the scoretable with JS/PHP. What interest me is to pass a variable from js to php to update the database. I've read many topics and all the answers lead to AJAX and this example:

```
    function score_submitting() {

var var_data = "Hello World";
                    $.ajax({
                     url: "submit.php",
                     type: "GET",
                     data: { var_PHP_data: var_data },

                     });


}
```

But it's not working. Im sure that the function can be called, cause when I put alert there, it works. But with AJAX happens nothing. The file is in the middle, cause it comes from game:

```
(HTML)

(...)
<body>
  <center>
<div id="gra">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="create.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="update.js"></script>  
         <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
      </div>

      </center>    
  </body>

(...)
```

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Check you console for any errors. See the network tab in dev tools of browser to check whether the request is going or not.

Comment: you need to define success or error callbacks to make test your response

Comment: After defining success/errors I got popups but site ramain the same. In console log nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GET request you should make your request like that :

```
function score_submitting() {

var var_data = "Hello World";
                    $.ajax({
                     url: "submit.php?mydata="+var_data,
                     type: "GET"

                     });


}
```

Or you can use POST request if you don't want to pass your parameters in URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can put success and error function for testing your code like following

you can also fetched data that is returned from ajax call as returnedData

```
function score_submitting() {

   var var_data = "Hello World";
                $.ajax({
                 url: "submit.php",
                 type: "GET",
                 data: { var_PHP_data: var_data },
                 success:function(returnedData)
                 {
                     alert('success');
                 },
                 error:function()
                 {
                     alert('Error');
                 },
           });


       }
```

Comment: I got popup "success" but site remains the same. I want to change website to submit.php wih my new variable. Also, I don't want it in the title, because someone could change it to get higher score?